# print multiple numbers in ascending order in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

So I'm working on this project where I have to gather 2 integers from a user 3 times (loop), and each time I have to print the two integers in ascending order. The restriction is that you can only have two cout statements within your loop (one is asking for their input and the second is outputting the ascending order).

My only issue with that is, when I think about ascending order, I would do it like (which has two count statements):

```
if (m<n) {
cout << m << n << endl;
if (m>n){
cout << n << m << endl;
```

So far, this is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int,char**) {

int n, m, z;

for (n=0;n<3;n++){

    cout << "Give me two numbers: ";
    cin >> m;
    cin >> z;
    //if (m>z);
    //cout << m << z << "sorted is: " << m << z << endl;
    // This is where I'm getting stuck because I need two count statements to organize in ascending order as shown above
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So have you considered to change which variable holds the lower number? e.g.

```
if(m > n){
    int temp = n;
    n = m;
    m = temp;
}
```

Then you can just use one print

```
cout << m << " " << n << endl;
```

Comment: I'm not sure i'm getting this, ill take it line by line:
Lets say m= 8 and n=2
    if (8>2) { // this drops into the statement as it is true
       
int temp = n; // in this one, we are assigning integer temp to be 2?
       
n=m; // we are assigning now m to 2?
       m=temp; // now temp is 2?

Comment: @RostamMahabadi in your example the result will be that m=2 and n=8 so it will print in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

> This is where I'm getting stuck because I need two count[sic]
>   statements to organize in ascending order as shown above

You have marked this post as C++:

Additional options to consider:

use algorithm lib:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::cout << std::min(m,n) << " " << std::max(m,n) << std::endl;
```

or use conditional / ternary operator in your cout:

```
std::cout << ((m<n) ? m : n) << " " << ((n<m) ? m : n) << std::endl;
```

References are sometimes fun ... but perhaps this challenge is too trivial.

```
// guess m < n
int& first = m;
int& second = n;

if(!(m<n)) { first = n; second = m; }

std::cout << first << " " << second << std::endl;
```

Pointers can do the same:

```
// guess m < n
int&  first = &m;
int& second = &n;

if(!(m<n)) { first = &n; second = &m; }

std::cout << *first << " " << *second << std::endl;
```

or you can use

- lambda expressions, or
- c++ functions, or
- c++ class methods

But I think each of these would be directly comparable to either of the first alternatives.

Comment: Maybe this is app is for a research project:  "When 2 numbers are requested, what percentage of the time will the subjects enter them in non-decreasing order?"  Oh, this reminds me: if the m and n are equal, what should the program output?  (or is this a trick question?)